# Dynamic Memory Allocation and multi-level arrays in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

Q6: Dynamic Memory allocation: Consider the following declaration for the multi-level array, 
names:

```
char name_1[]= “John”; 
char name_2[]= “Paul”; 
char name_3[] = “Stephen”; 
char *names[3]={name_1, name_2, name_3};
```

Create an equivalent multi-level array: dynamic_names that has all its elements and the data 
pointed to by its elements on the heap.

What exactly does this even mean? seems a little broad and with no direction to put me in... Would be very awesome to help!

Thanks!

Comment: The question is very specific and precise. There is only one way to interpret it. Perhaps you should read the course material again.

Comment: I just honestly don't understand what it even means... It's a practice midterm question and she didn't go over the answers so I'm kind of stuck. :(

Comment: It means you should create the arrays using `malloc()`.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, I think you haven't been paying attention in class.

Comment: I have. It just doesn't make sense to create another multi-level array when names already creates one..

Comment: Do you understand what "create an equivalent program" means? Hint: that new program should do the same thing your existing program already does, but in a different way. Is there any problem with this notion?

Answer (score 1):

*Create an equivalent multi-level array: dynamic_names that has all its elements and the data pointed to by its elements on the **heap***.

The *...multi-level array with all its elements in heap...* : `char **dynamic_names;` (Only a pointer because the space will be allocated dynamically using `malloc`).

Now the `3` elements in the array `dynamic_names` i.e. *...the data pointed to by its elements...* also need to be in **heap**, therefore, each of the `char *name_1;` , `char *name_2;` ; `char *name_3;` will also be allocated memory dynamically similarly using `malloc`.

P.S. : I have explained the problem in words. Try to figure out how to write the code for it. :)

**EDIT**: (After OP's Comment)

More explanation:

1. The multi-level array `dynamic_names` will point to `3` `char*` pointers.
2. Each of the three pointers `name_1` and similar will point to `1` `char` array of different sizes.
3. To allocate a space of `5` `chars` and assign it to a `char *` pointer, you write:
   `char *ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));`
   [Sincere Advice: Don't cast return value of `malloc`]

**EDIT 2**:

1. `char **dynamic_names = malloc(3*sizeof(char*));` This will allocate space for `3` `char*` pointers, and assign the base address of the allocated space to `dynamic_names`.
2. `char *name_1 = malloc(10*sizeof(char));` This will allocate space for a string/array of size `10` (including `'\0'`), and assign the base address of the space to `name_1`.
3. `strncpy(name_1, "John", 5);` This will initialize the space allocated for the first string (pointed to by `name_1`) with `"John"`.
4. `dynamic_names[0] = name_1;` this will assign "the pointer to first string" as the first element of the `dynamic_names` array.
5. Now you have to allocate space for other two strings and provide their base addresses to `name_2` and `name_3` and then assign these pointers as second and third elements resp. to `dynamic_array`.

Comment: char * dynamic_names = (char*)malloc(3*sizeof(char*));


char ** dynamic_names = (char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));

Something like that

Comment: Right? That's what you said... I don't understand it otherwise.

Comment: @LucasMarzocco : Close enough!! But not exactly... :)

Comment: so char* dynamic_names = (char*)malloc(3*sizeof(char));

name_1[] BLAH BLAH BLAH, same for the other 2

then...
char* ptr = malloc(5*sizeof(char));

Comment: @LucasMarzocco : `dynamic_names` will be `char **dynamic_names`.

Comment: So, last statement:
char ** dynamic_names = (char*)malloc(3*sizeof(char));
name1, name2,name3 initialization
and then char * dynamic_names = malloc(5*sizeof(char));

Comment: Thanks.. It's confusing as heck, but I think I get it now.... If only my professor explained it better...

Comment: much better answer :)